# Screen capture delay due to writing data in the file

Tags: android

I have a rooted device and I successfully capture the screenshot of current screen, using this code:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
os.writeBytes("/system/bin/screencap -p " + path + "; \n");
```

But in the command I provide the path where I want to save the file and the system takes time to write the image in the file. Can we directly take the image data from process in the form of bytes? I want to send the current image to the server immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible as pointed by **mah** as well.

The code below will help you keep the app responsive while you are writing the image in memory.

This is because the `UI/main thread` is busy in writing the captured screenshot in memory. So the easiest way to solve this issue is `AsyncTask.`

```
public CaptureScreenShot extends Activity
{
  ArrayList<bitmap> arrayListImage;
  int i=0;

  public void captureScreenshot()
  {
     i++;

     // store the image in arrayList "image"

     new BackgroudClass.execute();
  }

 private class BackgroudClass extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> 
 {
     @Override
     protected Void doInBackgroud(Void.. params)
     {
        // write the image from arrayList at imageArrayList.get(i);
     }
 }


@Override 
public onStop()
{
    arrayListImage = null; // making it eligible for GC
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This does not answer the poster's question. S/he's stating that the problem is the time to write the data to the file, not the disruption to the UI... the posted intention is to immediately send the screenshot data off the device and that no intermediary file (nor file write time) is desired. This is probably not possible to achieve, but it's what was asked for.

Comment: whoops I misunderstood the question. I have updated the answer. thanks man

Comment: Yep make your own app which runs a service in background for listening to button presses for taking screenshot and when you have captured the shot, upload it to internet. But this is alot of work in my opinion. The easiest way around is let the system take the shot, store it some where, rad the image from there and upload to internet

Comment: can you please explain how i can do this?@Umer Farooq

Comment: Well that kind of goes out of the scope of the question. So it is better to start a new question and provide all the necessary details there. I will be more than happy to answer. But before that mark this question as solved by accepting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

screencap should print the image data to stdout if you do not provide a file argument:

> usage: screencap [-hp] [-d display-id] [FILENAME] 
>   -h: this message 
>   -p: save the file as a png.
>   -d: specify the display id to capture, default 0.
>   If FILENAME ends with .png it will be saved as a png.
>   If FILENAME is not given, the results will be printed to stdout.

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
os.writeBytes("/system/bin/screencap\n");
```

You can then go and read the image data from stdout which you get with `process.getInputStream()`